# Не удаётся преобразовать лямбда выражения в тип делегата

Tags: c#

Чтобы не засорять тему,действую по принципу отдельный вопрос-отдельная тема

```
    public static double reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)
           {          
               NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
Complex u1 = U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(anguarFrequency), 0, T);//U'(w)
Complex u2 = U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Sin(anguarFrequency), 0, T);//U''(w)
Complex img = Complex.ImaginaryOne.Imaginary;// инициализируем новый экземпляр объекта complex samvalue(1,0)
Complex ValFurieTrans = u1 - img * u2; //Вычисляем U(w)e^-j*fi(w)= U'(w) - U''(w) 
return (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * GetSpectralDensity(U, anguarFrequency, T) * integration.Calculate1(t => Complex.Cos(anguarFrequency * t - ValFurieTrans), 0, T) + Complex.ImaginaryOne * (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * GetSpectralDensity(U, anguarFrequency, T) * integration.Calculate1(t => Complex.Sin(anguarFrequency * t - ValFurieTrans), 0, T);                    
           }
```

Я изменил код и добавил Complex.Cos и Complex.Sin но возникла проблема с лямбда-выражением
В строке с return он пишет где C`omplex.Cos и Complex.Sin`

Не удается преобразовать "лямбда-выражение" в тип делегата "System.Func", так как некоторые типы возвращаемого значения в блоке не являются неявно преобразуемыми в тип возвращаемого значения делегата

ЧТО МНОЙ БЫЛО СДЕЛАНО

Учитывая что у меня существуют методы Calculate(они double) и они мне очень сильно нужны. 
Я решил создать отдельный Calculate для комплексных чисел 
Но и тут возникли большие проблемы

```
interface NumericalIntegrationRule
        {
            double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount);

            Complex Calculate1(Func<double, Complex> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount);
        }

        class NumericalIntegration
        {
            public readonly NumericalIntegrationRule DefaultRule = null;
            public readonly int DefaultSubintervalsCount = 100;//100000

            public NumericalIntegration()
            {
                DefaultRule = new TrapezoidalRule();
            }

            public NumericalIntegration(NumericalIntegrationRule defaultRule)
            {
                DefaultRule = defaultRule;
            }

            public NumericalIntegration(NumericalIntegrationRule defaultRule, int defaultSubintervalsCount)
                : this(defaultRule)
            {
                DefaultSubintervalsCount = defaultSubintervalsCount;
            }

            public double Calculate(NumericalIntegrationRule rule, Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
            {
                return rule.Calculate(func, min, max, subintervalsCount);---    Неявное преобразование типа "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно 
            }

            public double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max)
            {
                return Calculate(DefaultRule, func, min, max, DefaultSubintervalsCount);
            }


           public double Calculate1(NumericalIntegrationRule rule, Func<double, Complex> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
            {
                return rule.Calculate1(func, min, max, subintervalsCount);
            }

            public double Calculate1(Func<double, Complex> func, double min, double max)
            {
                return Calculate1(DefaultRule, func, min, max, DefaultSubintervalsCount);
            }


        }

        class TrapezoidalRule : NumericalIntegrationRule
        {
           public double Calculate(Func<double,double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
            {
                double result = 0;
                double step = (max - min) / subintervalsCount;
                for (double i = min; i < max; i += step)
                    result += ((func(i) + func(i + step)) / 2) * step;
                return result;
            }

           public Complex Calculate1(Func<double, Complex> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)---"MainFormProg1.FurierTransformReverse.TrapezoidalRule.Calculate1(System.Func<double,System.Numerics.Complex>, double, double, double)": не все ветви кода возвращают значение  
           {
               Complex result = 0;
               double step = (max - min) / subintervalsCount;
               for (double i = min; i < max; i += step)
                return   result += ((func(i) + func(i + step)) / 2) * step;
           }
        }
```

Comment: А почему вторая `Calculate1` получает `Func<Complex, Complex>`, это так и надо?

Comment: Да Calculate1
Это я специально отдельный метод сделал чтобы считать Complex.Cos() и Complex.Sin()
Так как если бы я оставил <double,double> Func то он сразу стал ругатся на лямбда-выражение.
Он и сейчас ругается на них

Я просто создал новый метод и полная копия Calculate но с возвращаемым типом Complex

Comment: Я понимаю про возвращаемое комплексное значение, а входящее точно должно быть комплексным? Вы уверены, что вам не нужно `Func<double, Complex>` на самом деле?

Comment: После экспериментов с кодом получается что да.
Так как компилятор неумолимо ругается на лямбда-выражение.
Но про Func '<double, Complex> ' попробую
Поэтому и я создал копию с Calculate double

Comment: Вопрос не в неумолимости, он же в тексте ошибки чётко говорит, чего ему не хватает. Тогда приведите ваш актуальный код (таки `Func<double, Complex>`?), сейчас поправим.

Comment: Так, уже лучше. «Не все ветки кода возвращают значение» — это правда. Посмотрите, вы делаете `return` **на первой же итерации цикла**. Это явно не то, что вы хотите, правильно?

Comment: По поводу «Неявное преобразование типа "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно» — ну да, у вас `rule.Calculate1` возвращает `Complex`, а `NumericalIntegration.Calculate1` почему-то `double`. На это компилятор и ругается. Меняйте на `Complex`.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь в исправлении!
Проблема с лямбда выражениями решена!
Но я создам вопрос уже другой,так как из за исправления появились ошибки в других местах
Плюс я нашёл ошибку свою и исправил как раз под ваши подсказки и структура не нарушилась.

Comment: Вот и хорошо. Тогда перенесу комментарии в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблем этого вопроса стоит:

1. Метод `Compile1` сделать принимающим на вход `Func<double, Complex>`.
2. Цикл в `TrapezoidalRule.Calculate1` оформить в том же виде, что и цикл в `Calculate`:

   ```
   for (double i = min; i < max; i += step)
       result += ((func(i) + func(i + step)) / 2) * step;
   return result;
   ```
3. Исправить `NumericalIntegration.Calculate1`, чтобы возвращало `Complex`, а не `double`.