# Восстановление исходной функции через обратное преобразование Фурье,неявное преобразование

Tags: c#

Этот вопрос стал итогом 
[Не удаётся преобразовать лямбда выражения в тип делегата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530440/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment661867_530440)

[Обратное преобразование Фурье,преобразование между Complex и double](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530281/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-complex-%D0%B8-double?noredirect=1#comment661767_530281)

[Избавиться от неявного преобразования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529092/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Буду писать по отдельности код и пояснение(В программе они идут последовательно)
Выяснилось что мне не нужно находить U'(w)-U''(w) так как это алгебраическая запись комплексного числа.

Поэтому я нашёл по отдельности U'(w)и U''(w),а затем просто собрал их воедино

На форуме математиков сказали наличие АЧХ и ФЧХ в формуле обратного преобразования обязательны,поэтому я их решаю по отдельности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу напишу что пределы интегрирования у меня `frc,frc1` это мои границы частот построения графиков,так как судя по теории если прямое я интегрирую по времени сигнала(от 0 до ТАУ),то обратно уже по частотам.

Проблема в строке return

```
Неявное преобразование типа "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно
```

НО В ХОДЕ ЭКСПЕРИМЕНТОВ БЫЛО ЗАМЕЧЕНО,ЧТО

стоит мне только написать `public Complex reverstrans()` то проблема неявного преобразования решается без проблем

Как мне указывали здесь ранее,для построения графиков НУЖНО ИЗЪЯТЬ из комплексного числа действительную часть и по ней строить график

Вот так указали
При этом функция U(w) является четной (всегда) - а потому мнимая часть u(t) уйдет в ноль (математически), останется только действительная. Ее-то и надо рисовать.(с)Pavel Mayorov

Также представлены моя скромная попытка изъять действительное число из комплексного числа

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Numerics;

    namespace MainFormProg1
    {
        public partial class FurierTransformReverse : Form
        {
            public FurierTransformReverse()
            {
                InitializeComponent();                
            }

   public double U=10;//Амплитуда
    public double T=1;//Период
double shag=0.01;//Шаг
public int frc=-100;//Начало диапазона частоты построения графика
public int frc1=100;//Конец диапазон частоты построения графика
введите сюда код
            interface NumericalIntegrationRule
            {
                double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount);

            }

            class NumericalIntegration
            {
                public readonly NumericalIntegrationRule DefaultRule = null;
                public readonly int DefaultSubintervalsCount = 100;//100000

                public NumericalIntegration()
                {
                    DefaultRule = new TrapezoidalRule();
                }

                public NumericalIntegration(NumericalIntegrationRule defaultRule)
                {
                    DefaultRule = defaultRule;
                }

                public NumericalIntegration(NumericalIntegrationRule defaultRule, int defaultSubintervalsCount)
                    : this(defaultRule)
                {
                    DefaultSubintervalsCount = defaultSubintervalsCount;
                }

                public double Calculate(NumericalIntegrationRule rule, Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
                {
                    return rule.Calculate(func, min, max, subintervalsCount);
                }

                public double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max)
                {
                    return Calculate(DefaultRule, func, min, max, DefaultSubintervalsCount);
                }                                       
            }

            class TrapezoidalRule : NumericalIntegrationRule
            {
               public double Calculate(Func<double,double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
                {
                    double result = 0;
                    double step = (max - min) / subintervalsCount;
                    for (double i = min; i < max; i += step)
                        result += ((func(i) + func(i + step)) / 2) * step;
                    return result;
                }               
            }


            public static Complex GetSpectralDensity(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)
            {
                NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
                if (anguarFrequency == 0)// Учитываем деление на 0
                    return new Complex(U * T, 0);
                return U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(anguarFrequency * t), 0, T) - Complex.ImaginaryOne * U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Sin(anguarFrequency * t), 0, T);
            }

            public static double GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(Complex spectralDensity)
            {
                return Complex.Abs(spectralDensity);
            }


            public static double u1(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)//U'(w)
            {
                NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
                return U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(anguarFrequency), 0, T);
            }

            public static double u2(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)//U''(w)
            {
                NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
                return U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Sin(anguarFrequency), 0, T);
            }

            public static Complex ValFurieTrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)//Комплексное число U'(w) - U''(w) 
            {
                return new Complex(u1(U, anguarFrequency, T), u2(U, anguarFrequency, T)); 
            }

            public static double achx(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)//АЧХ
           {
               return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(u1(U, anguarFrequency, T), 2) + Math.Pow(u2(U, anguarFrequency, T), 2));
           }

            public static double fchx(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T)// ФЧХ
           {
               return Math.Atan(u2(U, anguarFrequency, T) / u1(U, anguarFrequency, T)); 
           }

           public static double reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T, int frc, int frc1)///Обратное преобразование Фурье
           // public static Complex reverstrans(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T,int frc,int frc1)///Обратное преобразование Фурье
           {          
               NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();            
               return (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * achx(U, anguarFrequency, T) * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(fchx(U, anguarFrequency, T) + anguarFrequency * t), frc, frc1) + (Complex.ImaginaryOne / (2 * Math.PI)) * achx(U, anguarFrequency, T) * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Sin(fchx(U, anguarFrequency, T) + anguarFrequency * t), frc, frc1);       
           }

           public string zedGraph_PointValueEvent(ZedGraphControl sender, GraphPane pane, CurveItem curve, int iPt)
            {
                PointPair point = curve[iPt];
                string result = string.Format("X: {0:F3}\nY: {1:F3}", point.X, point.Y);
                return result;
            }

            private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }


            private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                textBox4.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int T = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int U = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            double shag = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            int frc = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            int frc1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
            int frequency, counter;
            List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
            for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
            {
                values.Add(reverstrans(U, frequency, T,frc,frc1));
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = values;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 1;
            List<double> moduls = new List<double>();

            for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
            {
                moduls.Add(GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T)));
            }
            foreach (double item in moduls)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }             
       }
    }
```

Исключение

`Необработанное исключение типа "System.OutOfMemoryException" в mscorlib.dll`

Возникает при вызове метода drawreverse

```
public void drawreverse(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T, double shag,int frc,int frc1)
        {
            GraphPane panel77 = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane;               
            PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
            double xmin = -100;
            double xmax = 100;       
            List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>();
            for (double fr = xmin; fr <= xmax; fr += shag)
            {
               double angularFrequency = 2 * Math.PI * fr;
               values.Add(reverstrans(U, anguarFrequency, T, frc, frc1));
               values.ForEach(x1 =>list.Add(angularFrequency,x1.Real));               
            }   
            zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl2.Invalidate();
        }
```

Ругается на строку

```
 values.ForEach(x1 =>list.Add(angularFrequency,x1.Real));
```

В этой строке я пытаюсь изъять из полученных значений reverstrans действительное число.
Для начала я загружаю в список-List values все полученные значения
Потому уже с помощью выше указанной строки я хочу изъять из списка действительное число и добавить его как координату в list.Add
Стек вызовов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нельзя ли программу в полном виде, чтобы можно было откомпилировать? Причём, если можно, без графической части (она явно не проблема).

Comment: Без графической к сожалению не могу,у меня там вызовы методов подсчёта в методах drawgraph...

Comment: Вы уверены, что дали **правильный** код? У меня функция `reverstrans` не компилируется.

Comment: А можно вынести вычисления из метода `drawgraph` и передавать туда уже готовые данные? В таком случае можно будет избавиться от графической части.

Comment: public static Complex reverstrans там под double
 вот если её применить то он заработает,я там экспериментировал
По поводу public void drawreverse(double U, double anguarFrequency, double T, double shag,int frc,int frc1)
       
Там есть цикл for (double fr = xmin; fr <= xmax; fr += shag),
и в этом цикле происходит вычисление,xmin xmax это мои границы где происходит вычисление,а shag это шаг построения графика
Иными словами метод reverstrans начинает работать только при построении графика.
По идее я должен получить точку и отобразить её на своём ZedGraphControl

Comment: Ну, `list` ведь можно вычислять снаружи и передавать? Я думаю, графику имеет смысл постараться выкинуть из тестового примера, потому что вряд ли отвечающим на вопрос захочется устанавливать сторонние библиотеки типа ZedGraph.

Comment: Я оставил только dataGridView1 и listBox1,графики я удалил.
Я правильно всё сделал для тестового примера?

Comment: Уже лучше. Но ещё не всё. Откуда мы знаем, какие значения должны быть в текстбоксах? Задайте их просто константами. (Таким образом вообще отпадёт необходимость в UI.)

Comment: Я добавил их под конструктором формы с присвоенными значениями,с которыми я работаю и которые мне нужны для решения задачи

Comment: Хм. У меня вот такой код пробегает без проблем: http://pastebin.com/RJrhgeZD. СТранно. А посмотрите на stack trace в вашем исключении, а?

Comment: Да он без вызова метода drawreverse работает,всё выводит без проблем
Исключение возникает когда я применяю метод отрисовки графика
Я сделаю поправку в теме и пояснение и прикреплю стэк вызовов

Comment: А, понял, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в коде

```
double xmin = -100;
double xmax = 100;
for (double fr = xmin; fr <= xmax; fr += shag)
{
    double angularFrequency = 2 * Math.PI * fr;
    values.Add(reverstrans(U, angularFrequency, T, frc, frc1));
    values.ForEach(x1 => list.Add(angularFrequency, x1.Real));
}
```

Дело в том, что

```
    values.ForEach(x1 => list.Add(angularFrequency, x1.Real));
```

— это всё равно что

```
    foreach (Complex x1 in values)
        list.Add(angularFrequency, x1.Real);
```

У вас `shag = 0.01`, значит, цикл по `fr` выполняется 200/0.01 = 20000 раз. На каждой итерации цикла вы добавляете одно значение в `values`, а затем **каждое** значение в `values` добавляете в `list` (точнее, не само значение, а лишь его действительную часть).

На первой итерации, таким образом, вы добавляете одно значение, на второй — два, на третей — три, всего (суммируем арифметическую прогрессию) `(200001 * 200000) / 2` — около 20 миллиардов значений!

Немудрено, что получается долго, и что память заканчивается!

Думаю, вы имели в виду добавлять каждый раз лишь одно значение, то есть ваш цикл получается таким:

```
double xmin = -100;
double xmax = 100;       
// List<Complex> values = new List<Complex>(); // теперь не нужен вовсе
for (double fr = xmin; fr <= xmax; fr += shag)
{
    double angularFrequency = 2 * Math.PI * fr;
    Complex x1 = reverstrans(U, anguarFrequency, T, frc, frc1);
    list.Add(angularFrequency, x1.Real);
}
```

Comment: Считает медленно но исключение и ошибка неявного преобразования наконец-то исчезла
Спасибо вам!

Comment: @beginner: Пожалуйста! Считать по идее должно медленно, у вас же в каждой точки считается по интегралу, 200000 раз? По хорошему надо бы вычисления вынести в фоновый поток, но это не новичковая задача, конечно.